# How to restrict NGINX to give media files if user is not authenticated

Tags: python, django, nginx

in the urls i have  this url that leads to the `serve_protected_file` on each time someone is trying to access a media file

```
url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], views.serve_protected_file, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
```

the `serve_protected_file` looks like this

```
def serve_protected_file(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes)

    raise Http404()
```

This only works in the development environment

When i deploy then the files are served with the nginx and it gives me the file trough the url which looks like that

```
https://staging.mywebsite.com/media/img/531126758844.jpg
```

how to restrict it everything in my media folder is private and external access to a file should be restricted unless user is authenticated

my staging.nginx.conf looks like

```
location ~ ^/media.*?/(.*)$ {
    alias /data/www/staging/mywesite/media/$1;
    access_log off;
}
```

Comment: Check the authentication via Django and use nginx's X-Accel-Redirect header to serve the file, as I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173532/url-shortening-using-uuid-while-serving-files-nginx-django/51174160#51174160

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/ this should help

Comment: I am on production already my files are saved in the media folder docs, pics ... etc.. when user is logged in it gives the picture straight from the media folder in the db its saved the file patch instead of the file... which maybe is bad...

Comment: okay Eurica 2 hours of head banging since the media files are all confidential... i just deleted the media configuration in staging.nginx.conf and it works like a charm

Comment: See also [`django-downloadview`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-downloadview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay Eurica after 2 hours of head banging...

Since the media files are all confidential, I just deleted the `media configuration` in `staging.nginx.conf` and it works like a charm

so now is executing the django view..., nginx was intercepting the django view